# What is the disadvantages of removing HTML tags before indexing?

Tags: html

This is a silly question but I am bit confused. What are the disadvantages of removing HTML tags before indexing the pages?

Comment: I'm going to give this benefit of the doubt and assume there is a question here. Either way it's probably better off on Webmasters.

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? It's hard to understand exactly what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two good reasons.

- By removing all the HTML tags you're removing all the semantics of the text.
  This disadvantages any ranking algorithm - all else being equal, a page with "Tree" in a heading is more likely to be about trees than one with "tree" in the text somewhere.
- You're also discarding attributes that could be used to index.
  To illustrate, a link to an image of a tree might have alt text describing the tree. Discard the alt text, and your page might not show up in the search.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on *how* you remove them. If you use a smart library, like jsoup or tagsoup or neko, you get nothing but benefit. If you use a bad library, it can lose your content for you.

Comment: Can someone expand on this? Those libraries seem to be HTML parsers. I don't see how their use was benefit search engine indexing.

Comment: By avoiding treating the tags as words in the index. E.g., searching for 'head'